# Http POST request with body Go

Tags: http, go

I want to construct a HTTP POST request with a body using Go `net/http` library.

The function I am using to construct the http request is the following: [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequest)

```
http.NewRequest(method string, url string, body io.Reader)
```

I came up with 2 solutions, but I am trying to see which one is more idiomatic and extensible to support different body configurations.

```
Solution #1

bytesObj := []byte(`{"key":"value"}`)
body := bytes.NewBuffer(bytesObj)
```

```
Solution #2

bodyMap := map[string]string{"key":"value"}
bodyBytes, _ := json.Marshal(bodyMap)
body := bytes.NewBuffer(bodyBytes)
```

Ideally, I will move the code to a helper function that way I can customize the construction of the body. The helper function will be something like

```
func constructBody(someArgument) io.Reader {
  return bodyHere
}
```

Comment: Note: The second solution doesn't work for nested json objects and the first doesn't guarantee syntactically correct JSON

Comment: If the body is always JSON, then use the second approach to avoid encoding errors.  Use `bytes.NewReader` instead of `bytes.NewBuffer`.  What problem are you having with the `constuctBody` function?  Give some examples of the values you want to pass to `constructBody`. The second approach will work with nested objects if you use map[string]interface{}.

Answer (score 4):

If the body is already string, options #1 is more compelling to me.

If you are only working with a key -> value with only string, option #2 is better.
But this will become cumbersome when you have nested struct

But most of the time in my experience we are dealing with struct. I like to make the struct closer to where the http call happened.

```
func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    body := struct {
        Key string `json:"key"`
    }{
        Key: "value",
    }

    out, err := json.Marshal(body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }


    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://example.com", bytes.NewBuffer(out))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    req = req.WithContext(ctx)

    http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
}
```

And if the struct is used in multiple places, you can make a package level struct.

Answer (score 0):

To have it more reusable, you could create a jsonReaderFactory, which just takes a few lines of code:

```golang
func jsonReaderFactory(in interface{}) (io.Reader, error) {
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    enc := json.NewEncoder(buf)
    err := enc.Encode(in)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("creating reader: error encoding data: %s", err)
    }
    return buf, nil
}
```

**<kbd>[Example on playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UzONP6sauEH)</kbd>**